# Writing to hdfs sequence file

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a requirement that my MAP should read a big HDFS text file and writes it to the sequence file as "text_file_name text_file_contents" as key:value pair in a single line.

My Mapper then sends the path of this sequence file to Reducer.

Currently what I am doing is :

- read all lines from a text file and keep appending them to Text() variable (e.g. "contents").
- once done reading the whole text file, write "contents" into sequence file

However, I am not sure whether Text() is able to store a big file. Hence want to do the following :

- read a single line from text file
- write it to sequence file using (writer.append(key, value)  where "writer" is SequenceFile.Writer)
- do above until the whole text file is written.

The problem with this approach is, it writes the "key" with every line I am writing to the sequence file.

So, just want to know,

- if Text() can store a file of any size if I keep on appending it?
- how can I avoid writing "key" in writer.append() in all writes but the first?
- can writer.appendRaw() be used. I did not get sufficient documentation on this function.

Comment: AFAIK `Text()` is not limited in size, but stored in-memory until written, so the bound here is the Hadoop worker allocated heap size. How big are those files?

Comment: Currently my files are not that big. However, I wanted my program to handle such a case. Actually, I want to write the output in Json format inside the Sequence file. So, had a concern that, if the Json data happens to be big then I will be able to write only partial data in the first line of sequence file and remaining data on next few lines. However, even if I would be able to write a very big json data in a single line in seq. file, during reading it back from the file, it may not get accommodated in a Text() variable (due to heap size limit).

Comment: Why do you need to do this whole thing just in the mapper ?, the solution is pretty simple if you can use both map and reduce phases

Comment: @Sudarshan a reducer may not preserve order.

Comment: What do you mean by preserve order ?, do you need the file names written in the final out put to be sorted alphabetically ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer to your questions:

1. Text() can store upto a maximum of 2GB.
2. You can avoid writing a key by either writing a NullWritable or set key.ignore to false.

But when you go with the second approach first time also you cannot write your key. So better use `NullWritable`